# How do I reduce a DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: csv, dataframe, julia, reduce

I have this giant table counting several millions of rows, and I need to squash some of them. I wrote a reduce that does what I need, in Ruby, but it was too slow. I tried Julia, for fun, and I can get it done in half the time on an `Array` of `Dict`s. So, Julia it is.

However, I'd like to output the whole thing as a CSV, and I don't want to do that manually because I have some crazy escaping to do. However, the `CSV` package in Julia only seems to take `DataFrame`s. I could probably convert my array of dictionaries to a dataframe, but I came across a number of issues with `nothing`s and the likes, so I'd really, really like to be able to load my data into a `DataFrame`, and apply the reduce to that.

Unfortunately, `DataFrame`s don't seem to be iterable by row. Ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at [Query](https://github.com/davidanthoff/Query.jl)? Alternatively, you can create a loop over 1:nrow(mydataframe). Loops are generally the julian way of doing things.

Comment: I could do with a loop, I was just hoping I didn't have to rewrite my reduce function too much -- I already spent a lot of brain power getting it right, and now I have to go procedural? :P I'll have a look at Query, sounds promising.

Comment: Isn't Julia beautiful? No need to expand brainpower. You may want to look at datastreams.jl as well.

Comment: this does depend on your version, but for the stable you could look for [writecsv](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/io-network/#Base.DataFmt.writecsv) function; the latest version seems to have deprecated that in favour of a bespoke [DelimitedFiles](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/delimitedfiles/#Delimited-Files-1) module instead

Comment: The CSV package in Julia takes any data source that defines a DataStreams.Source.